# How to change the purple background color in grub?

Tags: grub2, customization

How to do this manually, not installing any tools?

Comment: How do you want to change it?  Add a background image, change to another color, ...?

Comment: @Rulet if you know the answer please put it in as an *answer* and approve it. Editing the question is not the correct method.

Answer (score 40):

This is my way:

- Before 13.10:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub
  ```
- 13.10 and later:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub
  ```
- 16.04 and later:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub
  ```
- 17.10 and later:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub
  ```

And change the grub background color as you want, in my case I change grub background to black (0,0,0)

```bash
if background_color 0,0,0 ; then
   clear
fi
```

Then, update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Please note that:** there should be a space after the color value, other wise you will always get a black background. And as a gift, try using this value `35,00,60`.

Comment: In case anyone couldn't tell, these are RGB values for the color.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04, `ubuntu-logo.grub` has moved to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub`

Comment: There are four numbers in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: 14.04 also requires four numbers.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has four values, you should update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple:

```
gksu gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/text.plymouth
```

and change black value with your color, in my case #000000 is black

```
black=0x000000
```

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I've decided to write the answer. I took instructions [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

In my case screen resolution is 1440X900. Somebody says that changing grub window resolution to actual resolution of monitor makes boot faster(but I don't see this take effect in last versions o Ubuntu). So I've changed and uncommented one line in `/etc/default/grub` to this:

`GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900`

Then to change purple background of grub I created the image, in my case just black image with 1440X900 resolution and put it in `/boot/grub`. So my file is:

`/boot/grub/gbackground.jpg`

Then I've edited again `/etc/default/grub` and puted a line in it:

`GRUB_BACKGROUND=/boot/grub/gbackground.jpg`

then I updated grub configuration with command:

`sudo update-grub`

That's all. Now grub background is black.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to use a custom image here, the wiki states that the image must not be "indexed", must be RBG, and it says you can export the image from gimp with these parameters to ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excerpt from [The Community Documentation on Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

> **Turning off the splash image:** This may
>   make viewing the terminal easier.
>
> 1.Press "c" to go to the command line
>   and then type: `set
>   color_normal=white/blue` or the color
>   combination you wish to use.
>
> 2."black"
>   as the second entry retains the menu's
>   transparency and should be **avoided** as
>   a selection if the user wants to work
>   with a solid background color.

Comment: The purple background isn't an image though.

Comment: Yes, it's a color combination that you can set with `set color_normal=xxx/xxx`

Comment: I think that only sets the colour (or transparency) for the menu, not for all of grub; and in any case there are lots of other possibilities, including creating your own theme.

Comment: According to here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays#GRUB_2_Colors, if you set the background color to black set color_normal=xxx/black , black should be interpreted as transparent so that you can use an image background. The purple background used to be an image in Ubuntu versions < 14.04 See answer by @rulet on this page (probably the same purple background image that shows as the default background for lightdm). However, on newer versions I think the file has changed or is a color value instead, I can't remember.

Answer (score 3):

I would first get your image, then bring up Terminal type

`sudo nautilus`

copy or cut image into `/boot/grub`.

Open the terminal and type

`sudo update-grub`

There you go.

Comment: What? Just dropping an image in /boot/grub will make it appear at grub menu? I don't think so.

Comment: @EricCarvalho It actually does. In `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, lines 163-168 there is code to search for and use an image in `/boot/grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a ruby script to do the same. It actually edits `/etc/default/grub` and adds a custom background to it. Here:
https://github.com/4p00rv/grub-background-changer