# I want my grub2 background to be black but setting it to black is not enough

Tags: grub2, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the purple background color in grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub)

The default background color for GRUB2 in ubuntu11.10 is a dark-magenta-purple. How to change this color to black so that I don't have a purple splash on boot. (I want to keep everything black and hidden).

The background color is already set to black:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme

COLOR_NORMAL="white/black"
```

> This is called the 'normal background' color in GRUB. The word 'black'
>   in this position means 'transparent' to GRUB2

Reference: http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Splashimages.html#Splashimage_Font_Colors

Comment: possibly your question is already covered by this?   http://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub

Comment: Yes thank you!http://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub