# Grub on start up changed color from purple to black?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

A while ago, i reinstalled 12.04 on my computer and a few day later when My system restarts after updating itself, the grub is no longer purple. It is  just black and I didn't change anything that could do that. my system works fine and there is no problems with anything. I just don't like looking at a black grub while waiting in the booting process. Can you change the grub back to being purple or choose a different color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terminal type

```
sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub
```

- for Saucy:

  ```
  sudo gedit /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub
  ```
- for Bionic (18.04)

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-gnome-logo/ubuntu-gnome-logo.grub
  ```

And you can change the grub background colour by changing the values of the 3 in numbers in the text document.

Black is this

```
if background_color 0,0,0 ; then
   clear
fi
```

and purple is this

```
if background_color 44,0,30 ; then
    clear
fi
```

Once you have finished editing that file save it and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Refrences [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758693) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub).

Answer (score 1):

Spent an hour trying to figure this out on Ubuntu 16...no posted solutions worked but good news I figured out how to do this, it easy!

in terminal;

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

search for "background" and change

> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
>       set menu_color_normal=white/black
>       set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
>       if background_color 45,51,53; then
>         clear
>       fi
>       ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

to

> ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
>       set menu_color_normal=white/black
>       set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
>       #if background_color 45,51,53; then
>       #  clear
>       fi
>       ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

*you need to comment out if background... and clear.

save. reboot!

This makes grub look far nicer when used to dual boot a Windows 10.

Comment: comment "fi" line at bottom.