# Dirty grub bootup screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.04

I have have dual booted Ubuntu and Windows 10. When I chose Windows in grub every thing is normal but the loading screen is purple. Even when I change grub theme to black the loading screen is still purple. How can I make it black?[image]

I think some misunderstand my issue. Actually when I turn the system on the purple screen show up and then grub theme show up and after choosing OS the purple screen show up again.

Comment: while choosing which 0S.. is that screen black?

Comment: will it help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1127217/739431

Comment: @PRATAP while choosing Windows 10

Comment: you mentioned black in your Q rite how did you achieve that can you explain? note that I clearly understood the pic you attached. I just want to know how did you apply black theme to dig further.

Comment: `nosplash` on grub command line should solve that. As a bonus have grub display a cool picture and it will stay up until Windows sign on prompt. Far superior it Linux in this area. I'd post a real answer but I'm on phone.

Comment: @PRATAP I used grub-customizer

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix command not found!

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used grub-customizer so cannot say what it is doing. There are a few people around that use grub-customizer so hopefully they answer. This might help too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub